# Enable Slack on Spinnaker

Tags: spinnaker

I have a spinnaker local deployment running on ubuntu 14. I followed the notifications setup guide but its a bit fuzzy. I would appreciate any help in getting this integrated with slack.

Currently, I added a custom echo.yml with the slack configs. But its not picking up. Did not know where to specify custom settings.js (deck) as mentioned in the setup guide (https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/features/notifications/)

I would appreciate any hints/tips. Thanks!

> cat /home/user/.hal/default/service-settings/echo.yml
>
> slack:   enabled: true   token: some-token   botName: spinnaker
>
> Distributor ID: Ubuntu
>   Description: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS  Release:14.04

Answer (score 0):

echo.yml

```
slack:
  enabled: true
  token: some-token
```

settings.js

```
  notifications: {
    slack: {
      enabled: true,
      botName: 'Spinnaker'
    }
  },
```

Under features at the bottom of settings.js make sure notifications is set to true.

Also you must invite the bot into the slack room, don't worry if the bot is shown as offline.

Comment: Question. Where should I define my echo.yml and settings.js?
I have both of them under /home/user/.hal/default/service-settings/ but when I do "sudo hal deploy apply" I dont see any changes in the /opt generated files.

Comment: any inputs? As I mentioned, I added the required fields to echo.yml and settings.js but they are not being picked up. Where exactly should I make the edits or place the custom config? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Halyard allows you to do this with `hal` - no need for file overrides:

https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/halyard/commands/#hal-config-notification-slack